# What is the correct way to import an ADT

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I have been following the steps outlined here: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/importing-resources-with-your-themes

My custom structures and templates are being imported. The problem that I have is that I also want to define an ADT to be imported. Nothing happens when I create the directory structure outline here:https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/creating-plugins-to-share-structures-templates-and-more

Is the "templates-importer" standard deprecated? Can the "resources-importer" and "templates-importer" not be used at the same time?

I don't see any exceptions in the log and there's nothing to indicate why the ADT is not being imported. I have checked in the site template that is generated and in the global site.

Suggestions? Do I really need to create a hook to import the ADT?

Comment: Can you mention your folder strucutre inside theme ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one of those two, but they share common code and functionality ([here are if...else statements](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/blob/master/webs/resources-importer-web/docroot/WEB-INF/src/com/liferay/resourcesimporter/util/ImporterFactory.java#L95-L107) responsible for chosing one of). If you use Resources Importer already, you can add your ADT's to *resources-importer* folder (in the same way it is done within *templates-importer*) and it will be imported as well.

I have a hook project which resources-importer which contains (among others) 4 ADTs. They are located in the following folders:

- *resources-importer/templates/application_display/asset_category*
- *resources-importer/templates/application_display/asset_entry*

First one is imported as ADT for **Categories Navigation** portlet and second for **Asset Publisher** portlet.